# How can I trigger an event on an element in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events

### How it works without Polymer

In JavaScript you can trigger an event by simply invoking the method on the element itself:

```
<input id="foo" type="text" onclick="console.log('Click event triggered');" />
```

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('foo');
elem.onclick();
```

This works fine, as can be seen in [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9b3e6fup/).

### Attempting to do the same in Polymer

Polymer however has a different syntax, and uses `on-click` instead of `onclick`:

```
<input type="text" on-click="{{ clickEvent }}" />
```

```js
Polymer('my-element', {
    clickEvent: function() {
        console.log('Click event triggered.');
    }
});
```

I want to manually call the `on-click` event on my `input` element every time a key is pressed. For this I'm using an `on-keypress` handler which fires my `doClick` event:

```
<input type="text" on-click="{{ clickEvent }}" on-keypress="{{ doClick }}" />
```

```js
doClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
    console.log('Keypress event triggered.');
    sender.onclick();
}
```

As per Polymer's event binding, `sender` here is the element which the event occurred on (my `input` element in this case). This unfortunately gives me the following output:

> Keypress event triggered
>   Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

The error happens because `sender.onclick` is `null`, as can be seen (on Chrome only) in [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee9v0em/1)*.

How can I trigger an event on an element in Polymer?

* *I've pinched the Polymer set-up from someone else's JSFiddle demo. This for whatever reason is only working in Chrome, however this problem isn't specific to Chrome itself.*

---

*Before anyone asks me why on earth I'd want to trigger the click event on an `input` element every time a key is pressed, do note that this is nothing more than really crude example and not the actual code I'm using. This was just the shortest way I was able to demonstrate the problem.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to trigger a click event is calling `click()` instead of `onclick()`, so the correct function would be

```
doClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
  console.log('Keypress event triggered');
  sender.click();
}
```

here is the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee9v0em/4/)

You can also call the function instead of triggering an event if you are pointing the same element

```
Polymer('my-element', {
  clickEvent: function() {
      console.log('Click event triggered');
  },
  doClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
      console.log('Keypress event triggered');
      this.clickEvent();
  }
});
```

here is another [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ee9v0em/3/)

Comment: A more general way of triggering events is via the [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) DOM api, or the helper method on Polymer elements called [`fire`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#fire).

Comment: @ScottMiles if you want to add that as an answer I'd accept that instead, that definitely seems like the intended way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Summary from comments per @scottMiles:

> A more general way of triggering events is via the dispatchEvent DOM api, or the helper method on Polymer elements called `fire`. –  Scott Miles